# Angularjs - unable to inject $ionicHistory into service

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Trying to inject $ionicHistory into service itself.
Can I write like this?

```
.service('$ionicUtilityService', ['CONSTANT', '$log', '$ionicHistory', function(CONSTANT, $log, $ionicHistory) {
var apis = {};
apis.clearNavigationHistory = function() {
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
};
return apis;
}]);
```

I am getting error

> Error: $ionicHistory is undefined
>   apis.clearNavigationHistory@http://localhost:8100/js/services.min.js:1:6223
>   @http://localhost:8100/components/customer/home/home-controller.min.js:1:206
>   jf/this.$gethttp://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:170:424
>   D.create/O.emit@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:446:19204
>   D.create/O.transition@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js:446:18728

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on that first line and check to see if ionic itself has loaded at the point?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried injecting it elsewhere?

I tried this:

```
.factory('MyService', function(TestService, $ionicHistory)
{ 
     var service {
     myMethod: function(){$ionicHistory.goBack()}
     }
     return service
}
```

And got no errors.